# Field value and stage retention in salesforce sites

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, tab, site.com

I have a VF page which is exposed as a site. This VF page contains one tab panel having four tabs.

Now my requirement is if the user fills values in first two tabs and then leave the page. When next time user opens the same page then he should be able to start from the same tab from where he left the page.

The values captured in sites are stored in the custom object.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the user info and tab info so that you can default landing tab by looking those stored values.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in, store the data in a Custom Setting. If the user is just a Guest, store the information in a [Cookie](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm) instead.